# Choose video from photo gallery with certain duration and attached location only

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I am working on an app which allow user to choose video from photo library using `UIImagePickerController`. I want to have some filter on the video e.g If selected video duration is > 5 mins video will not be uploaded. Same way the selected video must have the location coordinate attached with it.

I have done this thing in `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`. First I got the duration and validated it than I used `ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock` and check for valid coordinates attached.

All is working well but the problem is when I choose video from gallery it goes for compressing and after that progress I am able to get the duration and location. If user choose 1hrs duration video and it will take a lot time. and if it doesn't have location with it than also my app will refuse it.

- Is it possible to choose only those video which are < 5mins and have valid coordinates??
- Can we show only those videos which fulfill my app's criteria?
- Can I get duration and location by skipping compressing of Image picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your requirement, I think `UIImagePickerController` is not fit for this u need `AssetLibrary` which is totally customizable by Apple so you can get whole detail of all videos properties like `Size`,`Duration`,`Co-Ordinates` all this so you need to go through on "`ALAssetsLibrary` " for your requirement.

Please go through below link given by apple for filtering Videos & photos

[ALAssetsFilter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009723)

Answer (score 8):

You can let the user pick any video, but if it's over 5 minutes, force them to edit it down to your maximum duration.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType]; 
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 300; // duration in seconds
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

in Swift 5+ ,

```
        var videoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        
        videoPicker!.delegate = self
        videoPicker!.allowsEditing = true
        videoPicker?.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
        videoPicker?.videoMaximumDuration = 60 // in Seconds, default value is 10 minutes.
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.present(videoPicker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

[image: var]